# Доменное имя

Tags: домен

Дайте, пожалуйста, ссылку на какую нибудь хорошую статью, где подробно написано, как надо переходить на новый домен без вреда для индексации сайта в поисковиках.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вот как-то так:

- [301 редирект – корректная переадресация через htaccess и php header](http://sb-money.ru/article.php?a=75)
- [Как перенести сайт на другой домен](http://www.instructing.ru/experiment/newdomains.html)